# No MethodError Exception on scala sbt scala Project

Tags: scala, sbt, nomethoderror

Hello guys i have a scala Sbt Project and i'm getting this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.Util.safeGetSystemProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

it seems that the error is caused by the slf4j jar versions.
How could i fix this problem.
Thanks!.

Comment: can you add some more details like the version of scala you are running, the way you are packaging and if possible the entire stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The `org.slf4j.helpers.Util.safeGetSystemProperty` method was introduced in SLF4J API 1.7.13: https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/commit/37229d8d62198bff31072f2a38e2d57ecdadc483#diff-834453f38a9a96a56815c23ab71d9446

You'll need to upgrade to 1.7.13 or newer.